# Naming Pandas Series while stacking from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

A common workflow that I have in pandas is getting data from some numerical function in "wide" form and turning it into a "long" form dataframe for plotting and statistical modeling.

What I mean by wide form is that there is variable information encoding in the columns. For instance, say I measured some value at each of 5 timepoints in 10 different subjects:

```
wide_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5),
                       index=pd.Series(list("abcdefghij"), name="subject"),
                       columns=pd.Series(np.arange(5) * 2, name="timepoint"))
print wide_df


timepoint         0         2         4         6         8
subject                                                    
a         -0.670881  0.959608 -0.480081  0.142092  1.697058
b          2.369493 -0.561081 -0.183635 -0.807523 -0.421347
c         -0.908420  0.629171  0.196728 -0.907443  0.264352
d         -0.390138 -1.821304 -1.994605  0.225164  0.187649
e         -0.860542 -0.998323 -0.490968 -0.815570 -1.009524
f         -0.917390 -0.120567 -0.893095 -0.359155 -0.204112
g          0.557500 -1.522631 -1.175746  0.705043 -0.366932
h         -0.817043  2.204493 -0.305202  0.464969  0.280027
i         -1.137253  0.350984  0.095577  0.468167 -0.058058
j         -0.569986  2.438580 -0.514894  0.860504  1.397393

[10 rows x 5 columns]
```

The quickest way I know how to wrangle this thing into a long form dataframe is using `stack` and then `reset_index`:

```
long_df = wide_df.stack().reset_index()
print long_df.head()

 subject  timepoint         0
0       a          0 -0.670881
1       a          2  0.959608
2       a          4 -0.480081
3       a          6  0.142092
4       a          8  1.697058

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

The **problem** is that my "value" column is now named `0`.  I could do

```
long_series = wide_df.stack()
long_series.name = "value"
long_df = long_series.reset_index()
```

But that is more typing, requires naming an intermediate variable, and mixes method calls with attribute assignment in a way that really breaks up my flow.

Is there a way to do this in one line? I thought maybe `df.stack` would take a `name` argument, but it doesn't, and `Series` objects don't seem to have a `set_name` method that I can find.

I do know about `pandas.melt`, but it seems like overkill in this case of "pure" wide table data, and it drops the `subject` index which is important. Is there another answer here?

Comment: Maybe my real question is "why isn't `melt` a DataFrame method? This works pretty well: `pd.melt(wide_df.reset_index(), "subject")`, but it feels like it would be easier to read as chained method calls that can be read in linear order.

Comment: not sure why their isn't a ``melt`` on DataFrame, could/should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Their is a `name` argument to Series.reset_index for just this reason

```
In [14]: wide_df.stack().reset_index(name='foo')
Out[14]: 
   subject  timepoint       foo
0        a          0 -0.179968
1        a          2  1.559283
2        a          4  1.020142
3        a          6 -0.899663
4        a          8  2.983990
5        b          0  0.586476
6        b          2  0.055108
7        b          4  1.834005
8        b          6  1.226371
9        b          8  0.953103
10       c          0 -0.919273
```

You could define this if you want to as well (and would be a nice add to DataFrame):

```
In [14]: def _melt(self, *args, **kwargs):
   ....:     return pd.melt(self.reset_index(), *args, **kwargs)
   ....: 

In [15]: DataFrame.melt = _melt

In [19]: wide_df.melt('subject',value_name='foo')
Out[19]: 
   subject  timepoint       foo
0        a          0  0.374912
1        b          0 -0.016272
2        c          0 -0.510553
3        d          0 -1.532472
4        e          0 -0.115107
5        f          0 -0.101772
6        g          0 -0.020966
7        h          0  0.427469
```